# Call a particular array from a parent scope

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, scope

I would like to call a particular array variable set as i within the .addEventListener method in the script below, but currently I get this - "Cannot read property 'className' of undefined":

```
v = document.getElementsByClassName("whatever");

for (i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
    v[i].addEventListener('pointerdown', function() {
        v[i].className -= " scrolloff";
    }, false);
}
```

The error message apparently points out that the array elements of v designated as v[i] have not been set.

Is there a way to call a array variable set in its parent scope like this?

Thank you for your cooperation in advance

Answer (score 1):

Once the loop is completed, each element has an event function attached to it. But the function tries to access v[i], but i undefined now. Thats why you get an error. you can use `this` inside the function like:

```
for (i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
    v[i].addEventListener('pointerdown', function() {
        this.className -= " scrolloff";
    }, false);
}
```